Gremlin Query Execution Error: Cannot add a vertex where the partition key property has value 'null'
I’m trying to use Azure Cosmos DB for Apache Gremlin. However, the first time I try to add a new vertex to the database, it throws an error. I confirmed that I have already set the required properties and they cannot be null.
Here is the full error:
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      ExRam.Gremlinq.Core.Execution.GremlinQueryExecutionException: Executing query 827bd7f2-3ae7-4b70-93ae-ef0ef18a2951 failed.
       ---> Gremlin.Net.Driver.Exceptions.ResponseException: ServerEvaluationError:

ActivityId : 7be8d7fe-6e53-4970-9418-84c6835c4b0a
ExceptionType : GraphRuntimeException
ExceptionMessage :
        Gremlin Query Execution Error: Cannot add a vertex where the partition key property has value 'null'.
        GremlinRequestId : 827bd7f2-3ae7-4b70-93ae-ef0ef18a2951
        Context : graphcompute
        Scope : graphcomp-execquery
        GraphInterOpStatusCode : GraphRuntimeError
        HResult : 0x80131500

         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at ExRam.Gremlinq.Providers.Core.GremlinqClientFactory.GremlinQueryExecutorImpl.<Execute>g__Core|3_0[T](GremlinQueryExecutorImpl this, GremlinQueryExecutionContext context, CancellationToken ct)+MoveNext() in /_/src/Providers.Core/Factory/GremlinqClientFactory.cs:line 222
         at ExRam.Gremlinq.Providers.Core.GremlinqClientFactory.GremlinQueryExecutorImpl.<Execute>g__Core|3_0[T](GremlinQueryExecutorImpl this, GremlinQueryExecutionContext context, CancellationToken ct)+MoveNext() in /_/src/Providers.Core/Factory/GremlinqClientFactory.cs:line 217
         at ExRam.Gremlinq.Providers.Core.GremlinqClientFactory.GremlinQueryExecutorImpl.<Execute>g__Core|3_0[T](GremlinQueryExecutorImpl this, GremlinQueryExecutionContext context, CancellationToken ct)+System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Boolean>.GetResult()
         at ExRam.Gremlinq.Core.AsyncEnumerable.FirstAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 source, CancellationToken ct) in /_/src/Core/Extensions/AsyncEnumerable.cs:line 32
         at ExRam.Gremlinq.Core.AsyncEnumerable.FirstAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 source, CancellationToken ct) in /_/src/Core/Extensions/AsyncEnumerable.cs:line 32
         at AzheirAPI.Controllers.AccountsController.Register(Dictionary`2 request) in D:\GodotProjects\azheir\AzheirWebsite\AzheirAPI\Controllers\AccountsController.cs:line 267
         at lambda_method19(Closure, Object)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
info: Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.ServiceConnection[12]

Here is the Program.cs class where I tell the query source how to find my PartitionKey:

            var hostname = builder.Configuration["Azure:CosmosDB:Gremlin:Hostname"]!;
            var port = builder.Configuration["Azure:CosmosDB:Gremlin:Port"]!;
            var authentication = builder.Configuration["Azure:CosmosDB:Gremlin:AuthKey"]!;
            var database = builder.Configuration["Azure:CosmosDB:Gremlin:Database"]!;
            var graph = builder.Configuration["Azure:CosmosDB:Gremlin:Graph"]!;
            var fullUri = $"wss://{hostname}:{port}/";

            IGremlinQuerySource gremlinQuerySource = GremlinQuerySource.g
               .UseCosmosDb<Vertex, Edge>(configurator => configurator
                    .At(new Uri(fullUri))
                    .OnDatabase(database)
                    .OnGraph(graph)
                    .WithPartitionKey(x => x.PartitionKey!)
                    .AuthenticateBy(authentication)
                    .UseNewtonsoftJson());

            builder.Services.AddSingleton(gremlinQuerySource);

Here is how I define my Vertex class and its inheritance:
    public class Vertex
    {
        public string? Id { get; set; }

        public string? PartitionKey { get; set; } = "/AzheirGraph";
    }

    public class Edge
    {
        public string? Id { get; set; }
        public string? PartitionKey { get; set; } = "/AzheirGraph";
    }

    public class Account : Vertex
    {
        public string Avatar { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public required string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public required string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string FullName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; } = DateTime.MaxValue;
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
        public Gender Gender { get; set; } = Gender.Unknown;
        public int Points { get; set; } = 0;
        public bool IsConfirmed { get; set; } = false;
        public bool NewsletterSubscription { get; set; } = false;
    }


My csproj file
    <PackageReference Include="ExRam.Gremlinq.Core" Version="12.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="ExRam.Gremlinq.Core.AspNet" Version="12.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="ExRam.Gremlinq.Providers.Core" Version="12.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="ExRam.Gremlinq.Providers.CosmosDb" Version="12.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="ExRam.Gremlinq.Providers.CosmosDb.AspNet" Version="12.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="ExRam.Gremlinq.Providers.GremlinServer" Version="12.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="ExRam.Gremlinq.Providers.GremlinServer.AspNet" Version="12.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="ExRam.Gremlinq.Support.NewtonsoftJson" Version="12.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="ExRam.Gremlinq.Support.NewtonsoftJson.AspNet" Version="12.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="FlakeId" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Gremlin.Net" Version="3.7.2" />

Here is how it is being used:
            AzheirAPI.Elements.Account newAccount = new()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Email = requestEmail,
                Password = Argon2.Hash(requestPassword),
            };

           // This line causing: Gremlin Query Execution Error: Cannot add a vertex where the partition key property has value 'null'.
            Elements.Account createdAccount = await gremlinQuerySource.AddV(newAccount).FirstAsync();

            Console.WriteLine($"createdAccount: {createdAccount}");


I have tried to delete my graph on Azure and recreate it with the PartitionKey set to "/AzheirGraph". I also tried removing the "/" from this key, but that didn’t work either. Please point out what I might be doing wrong. This is my first time interacting with Cosmos DB and Gremlin, so I have no clue about what I might be doing wrong.

Change the following code
public string? PartitionKey { get; set; } = "/AzheirGraph";

to
public string? AzheirGraph { get; set; }

Bascially, the name of your partition key needs to be the name of your Vertex base class property. Make sure the spelling is correct.
My partition key name is "elementTypeId", and it's an int value.

So I changed my Vertex class property to;
public int elementTypeId { get; set; } = 0;

and it worked. I hope this helps you, this worked for me.

Thank you so much for the insight! I couldn't have figured out that it would work this way. My PartitionKey is "/AzheirGraph," so I need to create a PartitionKey property in my Vertex class with the name "AzheirGraph," and I can assign any value to it, and it works. I will need to do more research on what this partition key serves.

No problem, I am glad I could help. I had the same issue and it took a few hours to figure it out. Zero documentation in the sample template.
